# removing relative links from rss feed in python django

Tags: python, django, xml, rss, feed

When creating the news, relative links were added to the text of the news itself by [link_name] (downloads/generic/2020.04.1/)
When I load this text through the standard rss feed handler

```
class BaseLatestNewsFeed(Feed):
    link = "/news/"

    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.title

    def item_description(self, item):
        return markdown_text(item.preview)
```

and get

```
item><title> ... </title><link>https://example.com/26/</link><description>&lt;p&gt;this is a link for download: &lt;a href="/downloads/generic/2020.04.1/"&gt; 2.6.0.13508&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
```

I know that in order to solve this problem, I can add an attribute **xml:base="http://example.com/"** to the description tag, but I don’t know how to do it in django. Or maybe there are other ways to solve the problem